# How to get list of all existing Tabs within Tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I would like to know how to get list of all existing tabs within Tabhost to store their indicators to the List which will be saved to the SharedPreferences (json string format) when onDestroy() will be called.

I ask because I'm working on an application which has built-in multichat based on tabs and I would like to preserve list of open chats even after user will press the "Back" button...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how to get list of all existing tabs within Tabhost to store their indicators to the List which will be saved to the SharedPreferences (json string format) when onDestroy() will be called.

When you call `addTab()` to add the tab to the `TabHost`, also keep track of your desired information yourself.

Comment: Yep, thanks, I've decided to do it in that way but I wondered if there's another way similar to the one I explained in my question... It's strange that TabHost holds the ArrayList<TabSpec> which is not obtainable by any way :-/

Comment: @CommonsWare , But I don have method addTab(), In my case :   tabsLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);, So, how should I get the list of tabs (labels) ?

Comment: @NoorHossain: This answer is over 8 years old and is referring the deprecated `TabHost` in the framework. I am guessing that you are using `TabLayout`. You can use `getTabCount()` to get the number of tabs and `getTabAt()` to get the tab details for a tab given its 0-based position. That returns a `TabLayout.Tab` object, which has a `getText()` method.

Comment: Great Thanks for your quick reply, again thanks. I found this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66131833/7608371