# Get All tab ( tabs) labels in a list from tabs Layout Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I have set tab layout with view pager, As follows :

```
 sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), suraName, suraId, ayatId);
        final ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
         tabsLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabsLayout.animate();

        tabsLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Now, I want all tabs label in a list. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

So, how to get all tab labels from  tabsLayout. In oncreate after setting up all adapters, viewpager and tabsLayout (you can wait for some time also) :

```
         ArrayList<String> labelList = new ArrayList<>();

        labelList = tabLabelList(tabsLayout, labelList);
        if(labelList!=null)
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: list labels"+labelList.toString());
```

And :

```
public static ArrayList<String> tabLabelList(View view, ArrayList<String> tabLabelsList) {
        if (!(view instanceof ViewGroup)) {
            return null;
        }

        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view;
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof TextView) {
                String s = ((TextView)child).getText().toString();
                tabLabelsList.add (s);
            } else {
                tabLabelList(child, tabLabelsList);
            }
        }
        return  tabLabelsList;
    }
```

This way one can get all text from a view which has a textView as child.